# copy a google form retaining responses and summary charts

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, google-forms

I have wrongly submitted a google form to two different groups of people.
So I have created a copy of the form after generating the spreadsheet.
However, in the responses tab of the copied form, I get zero responses.

Can I duplicate a form retaining both responses and summary tables & charts, and even allowing people to continue to submit one of both of them and update existing summary tables & charts?

Comment: @Tedinoz You should turn your comments to an answer so it can be accepted or upvoted. Not many people read comments and you also help reduce the [unanswered list](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Unanswered)

Comment: This isn't possible by default. See my [answer here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/154041/271529) for an updated & improved solution in **2021**.

Answer (score 1):

**Q1:"duplicate a form retaining both responses and summary tables & charts".**

Yes.
Refer [Importing data into a Google Forms response sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28154/importing-data-into-a-google-forms-response-sheet) - your question is arguably a duplicate.

I've just used this to do a proof-of-concept (also, the 1st answer provides a great explanation of the relationship between form and spreadsheet). As @Rubén notes, the downside is that you can't edit the timestamp.

**Q2:"submit one of both of them and update existing summary tables & charts".**

No and yes.
TTBOMK each form requires its own destination sheet (that is, one sheet cannot be used by two forms), so I would allow each to submit to its respective response sheet.

Then I'd create a third sheet that "merges" the data from each destination sheet and use that merged data for summary tables/charts.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a built-in feature but you can use Google Apps Script with some limitations copy the responses from the original form to the copy.

One of the limitations is that timestamp will not be the same.

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script

> **Many Google apps, one platform in the cloud**
> [image]
>
> Increase the power of your favorite Google apps — like Calendar, Docs, Drive, Gmail, Sheets, and Slides.
> Apps Script lets you do more with Google, all on a modern JavaScript platform in the cloud. Build solutions to boost your collaboration and productivity.