# Is there a way to speed up the auto-increment routine in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms, google-sheets-performance

The solutions that have been provided for this [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15449/can-i-add-an-autoincrement-field-to-a-google-spreadsheet-based-on-a-google-form) does the job, but when more people submit data at the same time, things go wrong. The same number is used in multiple rows.

Is there a way to speed up the routine, or to lock the form when it is in use?

Comment: It's not clear to what solution are you referring. Nowadays it has six answers. Have you found something that works for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this - it uses the event handler and submitted data to identify the correct response and row, so it isn't affected by race conditions. A test function is included.

> I've also submitted this code to the original question, but felt that
>   the issue of multiple entries at the same time merited a response.
>   This technique could be used to similar effect for all forms dealing
>   with high traffic and needing connected scripts.

```
var FORM_ID = "YOUR FORM ID HERE";

/**
 * This function extracts the relevant properties from the event handler,
 * then uses them to get the uniqueID and record the response
 * @param {Object} e The event parameter for form submission to a spreadsheet;
 *     e has the following properties values, range, namedValues
 */

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var uniqueID = getUniqueID(e.values)
  recordResponseID(e.range, uniqueID);
}

/**
 * Records the unique ID for this response to the correct cell.
 * @param  {Object} eventRange Range in which the response is written
 * @param  {Integer} uniqueID   Unique id for this range
 */
function recordResponseID(eventRange, uniqueID){
  var row =  eventRange.getRow();
  var column = eventRange.getLastColumn() + 1;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(row, column).setValue(uniqueID);

}

/**
 * Returns a unique ID for the response, by finding the actual Response that
 * has the same properties.
 * @param  {Array} eventValues Array of: Timestamp_string, form_response_value...
 * @return {Integer}             The unique id (by 1 based array position) of the Response
 */
function getUniqueID(eventValues) {
  var isMatch = false;
  var eventItems = eventValues.slice(1);
  var eventTimestamp = new Date(eventValues.shift());

  // get the responses that match the submitted Timestamp
  var responses = FormApp.openById(FORM_ID).getResponses(eventTimestamp);

  //loop backwards through responses (latest is most likely)
  for (var i = responses.length - 1; i > -1; i--){
    var responseItems = responses[i].getItemResponses();
    //check each value matches
    for (var j = 0; j < responseItems.length; j++){
      if (responseItems[j].getResponse() !== eventItems[j]){
        break;
      }
      isMatch = true;
    }
    if (isMatch){
      return i+1;
    }
  }
}

function testOnSubmit(){
  var answers = [
    ["Sue", "39", "Okay I suppose"],
    ["John", "22", "Great"],
    ["Jane", "45", "yeah no"],
    ["Bob", "33", "Super"]
  ];

  var form = FormApp.openById(FORM_ID);
  var items = form.getItems();
  for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    var formResponse = form.createResponse();
    for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
      var item = items[j];
      var itemResponse = item.asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][j]);
      formResponse.withItemResponse(itemResponse);
    }
    formResponse.submit();
    Utilities.sleep(500);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This little modification to the script already present, will introduce a lock mechanism, preventing duplicate entries:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  // set sheet
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // Get a public lock on this script
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();

  // Wait for 1 second 
  lock.waitLock(3600);

  // get active cell / key
  var key = sh.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();

  // Release the lock
  lock.releaseLock();

  // add key to sheet
  sh.getRange(key, 3).setValue(key);
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but this solution does not work with my code.