# Pre-fill field with formula — incremental counter

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Docs form that I use to track my customers complaints. I want my customers to have a complaints number when I'm talking with them.

Is it possible to have a "counter" field pre-fill with an incremental number?

Comment: I refer you to these answer:

[link](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50965/how-do-i-implement-a-script-that-creates-a-unique-id-for-a-google-form-submissio) , [link](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15449/can-i-add-an-autoincrement-field-to-a-google-spreadsheet-based-on-a-google-form/50285#50285) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342684/hidden-field-in-a-google-form)

Answer (score 0):

Google Forms doesn't have a short ID or reference number. Instead it use a timestamp but it's not displayed to the form respondent.

Consider to send to your customers an email with the reference number to be used.