# How can I get a unique ID when I submitted an answer in Google Form?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I am using Google Form for my customers to submit their opinion. I read [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15449/can-i-add-an-autoincrement-field-to-a-google-spreadsheet-based-on-a-google-form/50285#50285) and [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50965/how-do-i-implement-a-script-that-creates-a-unique-id-for-a-google-form-submissio?lq=1), but I have some questions which these two posts haven't mentioned.

Is it possible for my customers to know their submission ID when they see the confirmation page?

E.G.:

> Thanks for your response. Your reference no. is #S201501. We will contact you within 7 days.

The second customer will have #S201502… etc.

Can I also check the reference no. in my original spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to dynamically change the confirmation/thank you message. However, you could use the [Autocrat add-on](http://cloudlab.newvisions.org/add-ons/autocrat) (or adapt its code) to send your customers a confirmation email with the reference number.