# Can one Google Form store a constant to be called and resubmitted in another?

Tags: google-forms

Long story short, I have two forms for a timed quiz, the intro form, which gathers user ID information and when submitted gives a link to the quiz itself. I use the relative timestamp between the two form submissions to calculate time taken for the quiz.

However I'm having problems with users circumventing the system, as right now they have to enter the same email address (as a unique ID) on each form. Users have figured out that they can use a bogus email to enter the quiz, look at it as long as they like, then go back and blaze through with their actual address.

So what I'm looking for is a way for the first form to store the email address as a constant, and for the second form to inherit that in a non-editable way.

(There are alternate ways to achieve this, such as generating two timestamps from within one form, but a search has revealed these to be seemingly quite difficult to achieve, so I figured this approach might be most feasible.)

I'm not a programmer, but have some basic capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Google Forms doesn't include the feature that you are looking for, however, it's possible to create a custom solution by using Google Forms but bear in mind that it will have several limitations compared with using other applications or creating a custom application from scratch.

- Use custom links to pre-fill forms, see [Send your form to people](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839588?hl=en)
- Use [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start) to create forms programmatically, store calculated data to a Google Sheets spreadsheet or somewhere else, send custom notifications, create workflows, etc. Here we have [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script).
- Use Google Forms add-ons to assist you on the creation of forms. See [Use add-ons & Apps Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en).

Note: It's possible to use Google Apps Script to create a web application from scratch. See [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

Related

- [How do I implement a script that creates a unique ID for a Google form submission?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/50965/88163)