# Auto increment ID in Google Forms

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am designing a Google Form for managing a congress registration process. I need to have a unique ID number for each registration and I found an answear here: [Can I add an autoincrement field to a Google Spreadsheet based on a Google Form?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15449/can-i-add-an-autoincrement-field-to-a-google-spreadsheet-based-on-a-google-form/50285#50285)

It was certainly very useful, but there is one litle problem I cannot solve. As the form has non required fields, the answears are different in length, so the ID is placed in different columns. I think the line in the code that controls the column where the ID is placed is this one:

```
21. var column = eventRange.getLastColumn() + 1;
```

Is there a way to place the ID in a specific column, say column C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `eventRange.getLastColum() + 1` with a number. Column `A` is `1`, `B` is `2` etc.

So if you want the ID to be placed in column `C`, change the code to

```
var column = 3;
```

Comment: That was very simple! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: Glad it worked out. If you found my answer helpful, you should _accept_ it (by clicking the green checkmark) and/or _upvote_ it.

Comment: Done. Sorry I dont know much of the rules in this site

Comment: That's perfectly fine, we all learn as we go. Welcome to Web Applications!