# Autoincrement in Google Sheets based on Google Form submission

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas

I'm trying to create an auto-generated unique ID# for each meetings being submitted via a Google Form.

The unique ID# solution must also meet the following requirements.

- The ID# must be static (not tied to row number).
- I need to be able to set a starting point other than "1" for the unique ID#'s.

I've tried the following solution, but it created ID#'s based on row # and if a row is removed, it duplicates a unique ID#.

[Can I add an autoincrement field to a Google Spreadsheet based on a Google Form?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15449/can-i-add-an-autoincrement-field-to-a-google-spreadsheet-based-on-a-google-form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with the following script: set a trigger "on form submit" for this function.

The customizable parameters are: the column number where to insert Id, and the initial Id.  The function uses Script Properties to keep track of the used Id, so they will not be repeated.

```
function generateId(e) {
  var columnNumber = 5;
  var initialId = 42;
  var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var id = sp.getProperty("Event Id") || initialId;
  e.range.offset(0, columnNumber - 1, 1, 1).setValue(id);
  sp.setProperty("Event Id", id + 1);
}
```

Comment: Bookend, Thanks for helping with this. I've tested the script and I receive the following error.  `TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 6, file "Code")`. I have not edited your code at all, just copy/paste into script editor. Ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: The function is meant to be run by a trigger, not manually.

Comment: Got it. It works with the trigger. Thanks again for your help!