# Can I add a unique autoincrement field to multiple answers in a column in a Google Spreadsheet based on a Google Form?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms, google-apps-script-triggers

I need to add a unique autoincrement field to multiple answers in a column in a Google Spreadsheet based on a Google Form.

I was able to add the function trigger in scripts but I need to add the autoincrement to multiple items from a dropdown in one of the answers. What I am trying to accomplish is create a media database with individual media file codes. For instance if one of my videos was filmed in St. Louis, MO I'd have something like "stl_adv_23" and if one of my videos was filmed in Tulsa, OK, then that entry would be "tul_adv_7" and so on. So when the user fills out the first form question and answers from multiple city codes in a dropdown, I want the auto increment to then add the next sequential number for that specific drop down answer not just the next in line overall for all answers. How do I do this in script editor?

I used [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15449/can-i-add-an-autoincrement-field-to-a-google-spreadsheet-based-on-a-google-form/141750#141750?newreg=8903bc6862df499998e79ba48d9b7853) as a jumping off point and it worked, but need the above additional function

Comment: Welcome. Please follow the [tour], read [ask] and add a brief description of your search/research efforts regarding what you are looking to include into the referred script.

Comment: Welcome. 1) Your link is to the question - there are seven, very different, answers; which answer did you use? 2) "stl_adv_23": I'm assuming that `23` is the autoincrement; `stl` sounds like "St Louis"; what does "adv" mean or is it not important? 3) Presumably if the next item in the response was also filmed in St. Loius, MO, the code would be "stl_adv_24". Correct?